An algebra as the generator of a non-commutative ring
I am using an older book, Advanced Quantum Theory by Paul Roman (1964), to study the Dirac equation.  Roman makes a lot of references to some terms in abstract algebra that I am not completely familiar with. While I certainly understand what he is writing, I am a physicist not well-trained in abstract algebra, and I am having difficulty finding mathematics sources to spell out for me Roman's definitions so I can confirm that I am 100% correct in thinking that I understand everything perfectly.  For example, I don't want to call something an algebra when it is actually the generator of an algebra, etc. ( Perhaps Roman's definitions are hard to find because they are old? )  Specifically, I am wondering about the exact nature of the relationship by which the Dirac algebra is said to be the generator of the Dirac ring.  Therefore, I will post the brief subject matter here and request clarifications or relevant references, thank you.
The Dirac $\gamma$-matrices satisfy the anti-commutation relations
$$
\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\equiv\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{1},
$$
where $\mathbf 1$ is the identity matrix, and $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse Minkowski metric tensor with matrix representation
$$\eta^{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1).$$
This commutation relation is said to be the Dirac algebra.  In abstract algebra, we call this the Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}_{1,3}(\mathbb{C})$.  This Clifford algebra has sixteen elements $\gamma^A$ with $A\in\{1,\dots,16\}$ that can all be formed from products of the $\gamma^\mu$ with $\mu\in\{0,\dots,3\}$.  For this reason, I think we call the $\gamma^\mu$ the generators of the of the Clifford algebra, whose elements $\gamma^A$ form a non-commutative ring.  Certainly the set $\{\gamma^\mu\}$ is not closed under its binary operations like $\{\gamma^A\}$, so one can be a ring and the other can't, but I very much want to ensure that I'm using the most precise language possible.
Here are some terms I would like clarified:
(1) Do the $\gamma^\mu$ form the Dirac algebra, or is the algebra their anti-commutation relations?
(2) When one says that an algebra is a basis for a ring, which object exactly is called the basis.  (I am 100% sure I know what a non-commutative ring is.)
(3) If the Dirac algebra is also the Clifford algebra, then at what stage do we decide that the algebra of objects that obey $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{1}$ has sixteen elements $\gamma^A$ rather than the four $\gamma^\mu$ appearing in the statement of the Dirac algebra as an anti-commutation relation?
Any additional clarifications on the names of things or their relationships to each other will be much appreciated.
THANKS!

There are different competing notions of what it means for a collection of elements to generate an algebraic structure (group, ring, vector space, module, algebra, etc.), but the unifying idea is that the structure formed is the smallest such that contains the generators. For example, for a collection of vectors, we usually speak of the span of the vectors, where we only consider linear combinations with scalars from a ground field; whereas, for a ring, we consider all finite sums of products of generators.

@SammyBlack I think this gets to the heart of my issue.  The smallest structure that contains the $\gamma$-matrices is the 4D vector space of the four Dirac matrices.  How do we get from there to the 16D vector space (what language do we use) spanned by the 16 linearly independent finite sums of products of Dirac matrices, which form the set in the Dirac ring?


I think standard terminology would say the $\gamma^\mu$, along with their relations, generate the Dirac algebra (as an algebra.)  This means it is the smallest algebra you can get just using sums and products and scaling with field elements.

I've never heard anyone say "an algebra is a basis for a ring."  An algebra is basically a ring but an extra nice one that supports scalar multiplication from a field.  I would say the $\gamma^\mu$'s are a generating set for the algebra.  I would say that as a vector space the Dirac algebra has a basis of 16 elements.

To be precise, what's going on with the formation of the algebra is that first we are taking a free algebra $\mathbb C\langle\gamma^0,\gamma^1,\gamma^2,\gamma^3\rangle$ (which is like polynomials except the indeterminates don't commute) and then we form the quotient algebra by the ideal generated by elements of the form $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$, which causes the free algebra to collapse a little so that the equivalence classes of the quotient obey the Dirac relations.  This is the same thing as the Clifford algebra with that particular signature.


It turns out to be 16 dimensional not because of $4^2=16$, but because all Clifford algebras constructed this way have dimension a power of $2$, and in this case it's $2^4=16$. It's not because you're doing pairwise products between the $\gamma$'s, it's because you can take any of the $2^4$ subsets of those four matrices, and form a product with increasing indicies, and that gives you 16 things, and they happen to be a basis (as a vector space) for the algebra.  Any other finite product of these matrices can be rewritten as a linear combination of those 16 matrices after using the relations, so they are generated by those 16.

The Dirac algebra is $\mathit {Cl }(1,3;\mathbb C)$ with the Clifford product usually written $$ A_{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n} * \gamma^{\mu_1} \circ \dots \circ \gamma^{\mu_n} $$
By the anticommutator relation, all factors are different, two equal factors are commuted to be paired to a number.
In contrast to standard mathematical Clifford representation with euclidean squares yielding $e_i^2=-1$, physicists adher to the use of selfadjoint operators and so use $$D=\gamma^\mu (- i \partial_\mu)$$ instead of the natural Dirac operator $$D=e_\mu \partial_\mu,$$ both with a square of $$D^2= -g^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu,\nu}=\partial_{ct}^2-\triangle$$
The different product sub-spaces of length $0\dots4$ represent scalars, tangent vectors, 2-vectors (generators of rotation wrt. to the metric $\eta$, forming a Lie sub-algebra), hypercube surfaces elements of current densities and 4-volumes or pseudoscalars.
By elementary repesentation theory the algebra is the product of two commuting Pauli-algebras $(1,\sigma_k)\circ(1,\tau_k)$, that can be represented as block matrices by replacing the matrix elements in a $\sigma$ with $\tau 's$
